# Updated to 2.3, now Product Pages Just Show Image

Tags: magento2.3.3

Not even sure where to begin with this one. Updated Magento from 2.2 to 2.3, and now when you go to a product page, only the image loads. There's nothing in the body but that and some javascript, then an error:

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getOptionsJson() on null in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml:46

Which is pointing at `"options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,` but I have absolutely no idea what getGalleryOptions is doing or why it would be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was raised as an issue on the Magento github and is caused by an incompatibility with custom code in your theme. you will find more info and a solution [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23432#issuecomment-511916538)

> You need to locate in whichever of your third party modules is
>   instantiating an instance of the
>   "\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" class in its layout xml
>   files and ensure it is injecting the argument "gallery_options" to the
>   block

Answer (score 0):

```
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml">
<arguments>
    <argument name="gallery_options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions</argument>
</arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml">
         <arguments>
               <argument name="gallery_options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions</argument>
           </arguments>
     </block>
```